# Creating xml node from Unicode string (encoding declaration not supported)?

Tags: python, xml, unicode, lxml

I have a database field which is storing an XML document as Unicode. However, when I fetch the field and try and initiate an `lxml` node, I get the following error:

```
node = etree.fromstring(self.xml)
ValueError: Unicode strings with encoding declaration are not supported. Please use bytes input or XML fragments without declaration.
```

The text I current have (`self.xml`) contains Japanese characters, etc. How would I create the node?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

If you have unicode, you can specify the utf-8 parser for `lxml`:

```
utf8_parser = etree.XMLParser(encoding='utf-8')
node = etree.fromstring(self.xml.encode('utf-8'), parser=utf8_parser)
```